# How I could handle a login prompt with Cypress?

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-chrome, cypress, prompt

I'm trying figure out how I could handle this kind of login prompt using Cypress

[image]

I read some solutions regarding prompts, alter, etc.. in this website [https://applitools.com/blog/testing-browser-alerts-confirmations-prompts-cypress/}](https://applitools.com/blog/testing-browser-alerts-confirmations-prompts-cypress/%7D)
But my code does not catch that kind prompt. Any ideas?

I was expected close that prompt and continue with the login process
Or there is a way to say to chrome don't show any prompt?

Comment: This looks like the internal basic auth form. You can visit the website with auth headers. That's how this login method works.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might want to follow this example in the Cypress documentation:

[visit() - Add basic auth headers](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/visit#Add-basic-auth-headers)

> **Add basic auth headers**
>
> Cypress will automatically apply the right authorization headers if you're attempting to visit an application that requires Basic Authentication.
>
> Provide the username and password in the auth object. Then all subsequent requests matching the origin you're testing will have these attached at the network level.
>
> ```js
> cy.visit('https://example.cypress.io/', {
>   auth: {
>     username: 'wile',
>     password: 'coyote',
>   },
> })
> ```